# Multiline Mathematica Expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to break an expression over multiple lines in Mathematica. How do I accomplish this?

I want multiple lines for readability, but they should have no impact on evaluation.

Some of my (failed) attempts:

```js
In[1]:= 2
+3
Out[1]= 2
Out[2]= 3
```

```js
In[1]:= 2\[NewLine]+3
Out[1]= 2
Out[2]= 3
```

```js
In[1]:= 2\
+3
Out[1]= 6
```

(Is the third usage a bug? It is multiplying the numbers.)

This works, but is ugly and undesirable:

```js
In[1]:= 2(*
 *)+ 3
Out[1]= 5
```

Comment: If you end a line with an operator, like + or - or * or / or ^ OR you have an expression with a ( or [ that hasn't been matched yet then MMA seems to assume that you aren't finished with the expression and will interpret the next line as more of that expression. But if don't have any of those, you for example end the line with a symbol name then it  seems to assume that you are finished with that expression and it will evaluate the expression entered thus far. Does that seem to be what you see with all your testing?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case, except I'm not sure why trying to escape a new line with `\` causes the bizarre multiplication

Comment: I am only guessing, but the backslash seems like it is guarding or stopping the usual interpretation of a character and instead treating that character as some sort of special case. So I'm thinking the backslash is keeping Mathematica from thinking that is the end of the line and is just some sort of literal white space. But we may never know what the real reasons are for some of these border cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an unmatched parenthesis to continue your input on subsequent lines:

```js
In[1]:= (2
+3)
Out[1]= 5
```

Or, try moving the operator to the preceding line, as MMA will expect the next line to be a continuation:

```js
In[1]:= 2+
3
Out[1]= 5
```